Why does integrating with polar coordinates give different answers depending on if $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ or $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is used?
When being taught polar coordinates, I was taught that in the polar plane the line of $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}$ was equivalent to the line of $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and hence could be used interchangeably. However, when finding the area enclosed by a polar curve, using these as limits, they evaluate to different values.
Specifically, I was trying to find the value of these definite integrals.
$$\int_{\alpha}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}(1+\sin\theta)^{2}d\theta  -\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}(3\sin\theta)^{2}d\theta$$
When $\alpha = \frac{3\pi}{2}$, this evaluates to $-\frac{11\pi}{4}$, however when $\alpha = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, it evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. If $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}$ and $ \theta = -\frac{\pi}{2}$ are equivalent, then why does this occur? Why are they equivalent as polar equations but not as limits in an integral?

The integral "does not know" where the integration boundaries came from.

We say the line $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}$ is equivalent to $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, because they are $2\pi$ apart, and if we go $2\pi$ radians around the origin, we are where we started. So the correspondence with your integral should be that $$\int^{\pi/6}_{-\pi/2} (1+\sin \theta)^2d\theta \Leftrightarrow \int^{13\pi/6}_{3\pi/2} (1+\sin \theta)^2d\theta.$$ The problem is you aren't shifting both boundaries, so if you imagine the arcs traced out, they're different when you only change one endpoint.

Thank you! I'm only just learning polar coordinates so sorry if this question was stupid.
